# Resolving Unkown custom element: <star-rating> vue js

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs, vue.js, custom-element

I am using Vue js in my javascript code.  I downloaded the vue-star-rating npm package to have a rating system for one of my elements.  I believe I have followed the instructions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-star-rating) correctly, but I am getting the error

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

### html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="../css/ProductEvaluation.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <button class="btn btn-sm" id="btnRun">Run</button>

    <div id="product-eval-areas">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="area in areas">
            {{area.EvaluationArea}} 
            // Error is occurring on this custom element
            <star-rating v-model="area.ProductEvaluationScore"></star-rating>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://url.com/WebResources/ccseq_/Scripts/jquery3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/papaparse.js"></script>
    <script src="../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/require.js" data-main="../js/main/ProductEvaluation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### .js

```
"use strict";

requirejs.config({
    bundles: {
        'https://url.com/WebResources/ccseq_/WebResources/js/lib/CCSEQ.WebAPI.js': ['Model/ProductEvaluation', 'Model/ProductEvaluationArea', 'API/ProductEvaluation', 'API/ProductEvaluationArea']
        //'../lib/CCSEQ.WebAPI.js': ['Model/ProductEvaluation', 'Model/ProductEvaluationArea', 'API/ProductEvaluation', 'API/ProductEvaluationArea']
    }
});

require(["Model/ProductEvaluation", "Model/ProductEvaluationArea", "API/ProductEvaluation", "API/ProductEvaluationArea", "../../../node_modules/vue-star-rating/dist/star-rating.min"], function (ProductEvaluationModel, ProductEvaluationAreaModel, ProductEvaluationAPI, ProductEvaluationAreaAPI, StarRating) {

    var currentProductEvaluation = new ProductEvaluationModel.ProductEvaluation(); 

    Vue.component('star-rating', StarRating);

    var areas = new Vue({
        el: '#product-eval-areas',
        data: { areas: currentProductEvaluation.ProductEvaluationAreas }
                    })

    $(document).ready(function () {        
        PopulatePage();
    });

    function PopulatePage() {
        $("#btnRun").click(function () {
            var productEvaluationAPI = new ProductEvaluationAPI.ProductEvaluation();
            productEvaluationAPI.Get(window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId().replace(/({|})/g, "")).
                then(
                function (results) {
                    LoadProductEvaluation(results);
                    console.log("success");
                }).catch(function (results) {
                    console.log("Fail");
                });
        });        
    }

    function LoadProductEvaluation(productEvaluation) {
        productEvaluation.ccseq_ccseq_productevaluation_ccseq_producteval.forEach(function (pe) {
            var newProductEvaluationArea = new ProductEvaluationAreaModel.ProductEvaluationArea();
            newProductEvaluationArea.EvaluationArea = pe.ccseq_evaluationarea;
            newProductEvaluationArea.ProductEvaluationScore = pe.ccseq_productevaluationscore;
            newProductEvaluationArea.SelfEvaluation = pe.ccseq_selfevaluation;
            newProductEvaluationArea.ProductEvaluationID = pe.ccseq_productevaluationid;
            currentProductEvaluation.ProductEvaluationAreas.push(newProductEvaluationArea);
        });        
    }
});
```

Comment: Try `Vue.component('star-rating', StarRating.default);` instead

Comment: `Vue.component('star-rating', StarRating.default);` gives error on load: `Unable to get property 'default' of undefined or null reference` @thanksd

Comment: So there's your problem. `StarRating` is `undefined`. I'm not familiar with the way you're using the `require` method, so I don't know what you're doing wrong, but it's not pulling in the `StarRating` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my package, but I didn't document how to use it with `requireJS` as I haven't used it in quite a few years. It is however bundled as a named UMD module which is defined as "VueStarRating" so you need to add the following to your requirejs config:

```
paths: {
  'VueStarRating': '../../../node_modules/vue-star-rating/dist/star-rating.min'
}
```

Then you can do:

```
require(['VueStarRating'], function(StarRating) {
  Vue.component('star-rating', StarRating.default);

  new Vue({
    el: '#app'
  })
});
```

You can check it out on this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lgz9vs4/

If you run into further trouble then it might be worth tagging your questions with `requirejs` aswell. Most `Vue` developers use CommonJS (including myself) so you should get better responses there.

Comment: Why CommonJS over RequireJS?

Comment: CommonJS because it allows you to use single file components and transpilers like babel so we can use ES2015 in our projects. Also, with requirejs you will need to pull in the standalone build that compiles templates at runtime, rather than pre-compiling them with a build tool like webpack which makes commonJS versions lighter. Finally many will be using [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) or [laravel](https://laravel.com) for their projects that use CommonJS as standard.